# Sails 0.11 400 response when posting JSON array to blueprint route

Tags: json, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm using *Sails 0.11*. Their docs say it is possible to post multiple objects to a *blueprint* route, just passing a JSON array.

I'm trying to do this, but I'm getting **400 bad request** as response.

This is my case:

I have a model called **Prediction**, which only has two fields, user (id) and poll (id). I'm posting this (to /prediction):

```
[
    {
        "user": "556b33e884eb522f02a4f52e",
        "poll": "556c4ff8243f03e501e2b65c" 
    }
]
```

And I'm getting a 400 response, with the following body:

```
{
    "error": "E_VALIDATION",
    "status": 400,
    "summary": "2 attributes are invalid",
    "model": "Prediction",
    "invalidAttributes": {
    "user": [
        {
            "rule": "required",
            "message": "\\"required\\" validation rule failed for      input: null"
        }
     ],
     "poll": [
         {
              "rule": "required",
              "message": "\\"required\\" validation rule failed for input: null"
         }
     ]
     }
}
```

Any clues why this is happening?.

**UPDATE**

I've also posted an issue on the *sails* repo on *GitHub*:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2977

Answer (score 1):

You POST array of Objects, but you need to POST just Object:

`POST /prediction`

```
{
    "user": "556b33e884eb522f02a4f52e",
    "poll": "556c4ff8243f03e501e2b65c" 
}
```

Comment: I want to POST an array. The Sails docs say it is permitted, so multiple rows are added to the DB in just one POST. Check the docs http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Create.html

Comment: Well, I checked. Sails always gives an error if save array through Blueprint. So, even if there is written that "Nested objects and arrays passed in as parameters are handled the same way as if they were passed into the model's .create() method."  - that do not work. So you may pass an array to Controller and save through `Prediction.create()`

Comment: Yep I already posted the issue to the **sails** repo, so they're aware that it is not working. For now I'll just implement a custom create action on Prediction. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Not at all. Could you post link to issue in you post, please?

Comment: Updated the post with the issue link!